# How to calculate the area of an irregular shape in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I've drawn an irregular shape in illustrator
and I want to know what its area is
then I want to compare it between another shape

How could I calculate its area in Illustrator (CS6 or CC)?

Answer (score 5):

There's unfortunately no way of getting the area in Illustrator (CS6/CC) natively that I know of.

You may have more luck with scripts.

I found one [here](http://blog.k8baldwin.com/Finding-areas-and-lengths-in-Illustrator-td4.html) that seems to work.

The code seems rather simple:

`alert("Area & Length (inches)\nArea: " + (Math.abs(app.activeDocument.selection[0].area/5184).toFixed(3)) + "\nLength: " + (app.activeDocument.selection[0].length/72).toFixed(3));`

You could also convert these measurements from inches to centimeters. [The source page](http://blog.k8baldwin.com/Finding-areas-and-lengths-in-Illustrator-td4.html) seems to go into some descriptions on how to customize it.

**Getting area in CS-CS5**

That being said you *can* look at it through an unsupported feature in CS5 and below (down to CS I believe) by clicking:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

or

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Select your path then open the `object` section and look at the area read-out:
[image]

I can't tell you how to interpret that area read-out (I'd assume points) but you can use it as a point of comparison. No pun intended.

Do be careful with this feature as it is unsupported and could cause grief.

[*Source and alternative methods*](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/317745)

Comment: Note the dev panel at F12 **no longer exists** past Illustrator CS5. Adobe removed the panel in CS6 and has not replaced it. It was never intended to be a feature or something users saw.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm working on cc :\

Comment: @Scott, good to know. That was something I wasn't sure about and took for granted. I hope that my answer can still help anyone below CS6 and perhaps some of the other methods mentioned in the thread I linked to provide some sort of answer. Other than that I don't see another way of doing this.

Comment: The panel was very helpful for this stuff and it's a shame Adobe removed it. But, like you, I'm unaware of any other method to see this data in newer versions. Hopefully someone will know.

Comment: @Scott I've updated my answer. The script seems to work in CC as well. Not entirely sure on the accuracy as my math skills aren't too hot, but it seems to do the job.

Comment: and a +1 to go with it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Bryan Buchanan made a [script available on github](https://gist.github.com/bryanbuchanan/11387501) to compute the area of a shape in Illustrator in squared cm or squared inches. I used it on Adobe Illustrator CC 2020.

In order to use the script you have to:

1. Download the file as `.jsx` (right click on "raw" and then "save as" somewhere on you computer).
2. Select in Illustrator the shape(s) you want to measure with the black arrow
3. Go to `File/Scripts/Other scripts...` (or shortcut `Ctrl+F12`)
4. Select the `.jsx` file in the folder pannel

The shape(s) area will be displayed in a pop-up window.

If you want the script to appear directly in the `File/Script` menu, you have to place the ".jsx" file in the subfolder `Scripts` in `Presets`. The exact path to that folder depends on you operating system, Illustrator version and language, but should look like this on Windows:

`C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator 20xx\Presets\en_GB\Scripts`

Answer (score 2):

If Johannes method fails to work for you, Telegraphics have a free Patharea filter which may do the trick: http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/patharea

Comment: thank you, the plug-in extension is >dmg 
and the plug-ins in the folder of illustrator files are .aip 
so, how to deal with ?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a Mac. The dmg contains the aip that you're after

Comment: Very nice. Double-click the downloaded archive, drag the 'PathArea (CS6).aip' file to Illustrator's Plug-ins folder, and launch Illustrator. The command appears under the menus: Object > Filters > Telegraphics > Path area.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Photoshop as a supplementary tool and can accept some error, say 0,4% of the area of the bounding box of the shape you can try this.

Let's have in illustrator a vector shape:

[image]

Its bounding box has W=98,8 mm and H=89,8 mm. The area of the bounding box is 8872,24 square millimeters.

Copy the shape to the clipboard, open in Photoshop a new RGB image which takes its size from the clipboard. Paste to that image as pixels the shape from the Illustrator.

You should have in Photoshop pixel dimensions at least few hundred pixels to get the max available accuracy. If needed open bigger image before pasting, scale the shape to bigger size and crop the image to the minimum which covers the pasted shape.

Change the color of the pasted shape to full white (RGB=255,255,255) with levels or curves:

[image]

Insert a background layer full of black. Merge the shape and the background layer:

[image]

Apply Filter > Blur > Average. Check the color with the info panel:

[image]

The color is RGB 117,117,117. Number 117 shows that the area is (117/255 )x( 8872,24 square millimeters) = 4071 sq.mm.

RGB numbers have only scale 0....255 with steps =1. The error can be 8872,24/255 sq.mm = 35 sq.mm. or less.

Another unasked, but available tool is Inkscape. It has extension Visualize Path > Measure. It can in Inkscape 1.0 calculate areas and path lengths of single Bezier curve shapes (=rectangles and other preset shapes must be coverted to paths). Groups are not supported. Every item of a group is measured separately.

The result is written as text to the image.