# Outline Dashed Line Stroke: How to order objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, illustrator-scripting

I'm trying to use Outline Stroke on a dashed line but it creates a bunch of objects that cascade down to both sides, like so:

[image]

Is there a way to make Outline Stroke follow one direction through the whole path, closed or open so that I can [add numbers in the style of "connect the dots"](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/57919/8708)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hiroyuki Sato** has made a script called **[breakDashes](https://github.com/shspage/illustrator-scripts#breakdashesjsx)** that can do this kind of stuff for you. The script is a bit temperamental and may change your stroke adjustments a bit but proceeds to do this in stroking order. Also the strokes still need to be expanded if you want them as circles.

An alternate approaches (that do what you ask but not with method you outline):

1. For circle is just to rotate clone circles circularly, though i doubt that's your usecase.
2. For a arbitrary shape measure [shape length](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42175/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-an-irregular-shape-in-adobe-illustrator) then make a cirle pattern as long and make it a brush. Apply brush to path. Expand. Or  use a pattern brush (this works as long as your shape is not too steep.)  Or even easier scatter brush.

[image]

**Image 1**: Expansion done with alternate method 2.